# Windows server 2008r2 multicast & igmp issue

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, multicast, igmp

I'm running multicast on a Windows 2008 R2 server and see an intermittent problem with
the router turning off multicast for a group I've joined. Upon using wireshark and looking at the IGMP traffic I see that sometimes there is no IGMP membership report sent when the router has sent out a general IGMP query. For example, if I've joined 4 groups sometimes I see responses from all four, sometimes three, sometimes two. I set the expiry time to 300 seconds in the router to, in theory, compensate for this, which hasn't always guaranteed success.
When the router stops a feed, it restarts it after 120 seconds, which for the data I'm reading is too large of a gap to try to fill.

Is this something that can be fixed? This doesn't seem like normal behaviour.